# Refreshing Chart area

Tags: vb.net, charts, datagridview

I am trying to plot a chart from a datagridview. My problem is that when selecting a combobox item and clicking an Ok button, the data is filtered and plotted in the chart Area, but when selecting another item, the plot is added to the first one.

How can I refresh chart area before selecting a new item?

My code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim d3 As New ChartArea3DStyle
    d3.Enable3D = True

    Me.RGPHReqBindingSource1.Filter = "[name] LIKE '" & Combo_com.SelectedItem & "%'"

    For Count As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 2
        Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(DataGridView2.Item(0, Count).Value, DataGridView2.Item(1, Count).Value)
        Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = False
        Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 0
        Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = 5
        Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").Area3DStyle = d3
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Title = "Classes des pentes"
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Title = "Pourcentage %"
    Next

    For Count2 As Integer = 0 To DataGridView6.Rows.Count - 2

        Chart2.Series(0).Points.AddXY(DataGridView6.Columns(0).HeaderText, DataGridView6.Item(0, Count2).Value)
        Chart2.ChartAreas("ChartArea2").AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = False
        Chart2.ChartAreas("ChartArea2").AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 0
        Chart2.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Title = "Type de Cheptel"
        Chart2.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Title = "Effectif Nombre de Tête"

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i have update chart in loop.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim d3 As New ChartArea3DStyle
    d3.Enable3D = True

    Me.RGPHReqBindingSource1.Filter = "[name] LIKE '" & Combo_com.SelectedItem & "%'"

    For Count As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 2
        Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(DataGridView2.Item(0, Count).Value, DataGridView2.Item(1, Count).Value)
        Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = False
        Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 0
        Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = 5
        Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").Area3DStyle = d3
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Title = "Classes des pentes"
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Title = "Pourcentage %"
        Chart1.Update()
    Next

    For Count2 As Integer = 0 To DataGridView6.Rows.Count - 2

        Chart2.Series(0).Points.AddXY(DataGridView6.Columns(0).HeaderText,DataGridView6.Item(0, Count2).Value)
        Chart2.ChartAreas("ChartArea2").AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = False
        Chart2.ChartAreas("ChartArea2").AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 0
        Chart2.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Title = "Type de Cheptel"
        Chart2.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Title = "Effectif Nombre de Tête"
        Chart2.Update()
    Next

End Sub
```